# Return the Stream directly or return a Func<Stream> when method opens up a stream

Tags: c#, stream

I have a class that implements `IDisposable` and a method that returns `Stream`.

What I'm wondering is it better to return the stream directly so:

```
public Stream GetStream()
{
     var stream = new FileStream(_fileName,  FileMode.Open);
     return stream;
}
```

Or it is better to return a `Func<stream>` and let the caller decide when to 'trigger it':

```
public Func<Stream> GetStream()
{
     var openStream() => new FileStream(_fileName,  FileMode.Open);
     return openStream;
}
```

I've tried doing my own research and although there appears to be many similar answers, I haven't found one quite like this. Looking at the existing answers, I am still unsure if one is clearly better than the other.

I think the second method provides more flexibility since we're not returning an open stream, we are opening the stream and allowing the user to open the stream when it suits them might be preferable. For example:

```
var listOfStreamFunc = new List<Func<Stream>>(){
   somewhere1.GetStreamFunc(),
   somewhere2.GetStreamFunc()
};

SomeMethod(listOfStreamFunc);
```

Then we are able to defer the opening of the stream to `SomeMethod`, which is favourable since the stream is opened only when necessary, along with reducing the possibility of misuse by accidentally prematurely closing the stream e.g.

```
using (x = GetStream()){
   SomeMethod(x);
}
```

Any strong reason not to go with the second option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Func<Stream>` approach allows you to defer opening the stream, but if you really want to defer opening it then just don't call `Stream GetStream()` in the first place!

Besides, if you follow your thought process all the way then you'd end up wrapping everything in a `Func`, for example:

```
Func<int> Add(int a, int b)
{
  var adder = () => a + b;
  return adder;
}
```

Clearly there's nothing to be gained here by thinking the user can call adder, and then "trigger it" when they want the result!

Also, the name `GetStream` really doesn't document what the method does (as it doesn't give you a stream). If you're looking to return a `Func<Stream>` then give it a better name, for example:

```
Func<Stream> CreateStreamOpener()
{
  return ....
}
```

Now it's much more explicit.

Note that ultimately this doesn't reduce the risk of misuse as you are eventually going to have to have a raw `Stream` object that you manage.

The fact that your class implements `IDisposable` isn't relevant here as you're not holding onto the `Stream` that you create, so it's down to the caller to dispose of the stream, not your class.

Comment: "if you really want to defer opening it then just don't call Stream GetStream() in the first place" - When you put it like that, it makes sense. If a caller needs to truly defer execution, then there is nothing stopping them from wrapping that call into a `Func` anyway to achieve the same behaviour. Agreed about naming & the rest - thanks Sean!